# How to import APIDEMOS into my project

Tags: android, api

I am using eclipse helios.I am importing android samples.But when I am importing project it is showing message that no project is selected.Any idea.

Comment: You need to import the demos into a specific project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lazy copypasta at OP's request:

> You need to import the demos into a specific project.